# Cannot find libssl.so.10 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vpn, openssl

I am trying to use SoftEther VPN on ubuntu 18.04.

```
vpnclient 
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So i found solution on google.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

And then

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

but the result disappointed me.
The result is same to original.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by the result disappointed you? Can you provide the exact error?

Comment: I have found solution. <patchelf> helped me.

Comment: there are some lib files missing in the new versons please copy those lib depedencies from any other flavours of linux and copy to the exact path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the directory where the binary/library located has changed, try this.

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But result is same. Are there any other way?

Comment: Link them to `/usr/lib` directory, probably they get recognized by now.

Comment: I have [edit]ed my answer, please look into it. It's the same command with little modification, just run them one-by-one.

Comment: The difference is file `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` now getting linked to `/usr/lib` directory, where this dir known as global directory for library, so it should be recognized. Then you can continue to work on your SoftEther VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works good.

Comment: Dear sir. I have one problem.I did it the way you told me before, then i have following errors.```/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /home/xxx/Working/SoftEtherVPN/bin/vpnclient)``` How to solve this problem? I will wait your reply.

Comment: @Nabi What are you trying to run prior to the error ?

Comment: I am trying to start softether vpn client service. So i used following command.```sudo vpnclient start``` And then above error occured.

Comment: And sir, I am beginner.So please explain about this error one by one .I think openssl version does not mismatch.How to fix this problem?I am sorry.

Comment: I had no idea since this `libcrypto.so.10` file doesn't reside in Ubuntu repository, you can try reinstall the SoftEther VPN or simply from repository https://code.launchpad.net/~paskal-07/+archive/ubuntu/softethervpn.

Comment: Thanks. It works good. And how to make qt environment without installing qt5?That is, I want to install qt library.Help me....

Comment: Save that for [New question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).